# Changing the text in a div

Tags: javascript

I have an assignment where the first part is to change the background with radio buttons. I have that, but the second part is to create a div with some basic text to start out. Then I have to create a form that has a textarea and use document.getElementById('yourelementid') to both find the value of the textarea and to change the basic text created in the div. I am stuck. Here is what I have so far:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>Change Background Color With Radio Buttons</title>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html"
charset=iso-8859-1" />
<script type"text/javascript">
function getInputValue() {
  var radioObj = document.forms["myForm"]["colorc"];
  for (var i=0; i<radioObj.length; i++) {
    if (radioObj[i].checked)
      return radioObj[i].value;
  }
  alert("No radio button was selected.")
}

function change_it() {
  var a = getInputValue();
  if(a=="pink") {
    document.body.style.background=a
    return false;
  } else if(a=="orange") {
    document.body.style.background=a
    return false;
  } else if(a=="yellow") {
    document.body.style.background=a
    return false;
  }
}
document.getElementById('mytextarea').innerHTML = "The text has been changed!";
</script>
</head>
<body>
<h4>Change background color to:</h4>
<form name="myForm">
  <input type="radio" name="colorc" value="pink">Pink <br>
  <input type="radio" name="colorc" value="orange">Orange <br>
  <input type="radio" name="colorc" value="yellow">Yellow <br/> <br />
  <input type="button" value="Change Background" name="Change Background" onclick="return change_it()"> 
</form>
</br>
<h4>Add text to this box to change the text below:</h4>
<div id="divid">You will change this text</div>
<form>
<textarea rows="3" col="25" id="mytextarea">You will change this text
</textarea></br>
</br>
<button type="button" onClick="changeText()">Change Text</button>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The `changeText` function is not defined. Looks like it should surround `document.getElementById('mytextarea').innerHTML = "The text has been changed!";` which is the last line in the `<script>` tag.

Comment: Side note: You can drastically simplify your `change_it` function. Look at and think about it. What is the `if` statement actually doing? (rhetorical question, please don't answer ;))

Comment: Is your teacher okay with asking for help online for assignments like this? If I were running the class, I'd disallow it, on the grounds that you'll learn more from struggling through on your own.

Comment: I've been struggling for 3 days. I'm not asking for answers, just help.

Comment: @user838056 Fair enough.  @Am's answer raises a couple of good points, as does @Felix King's.  Beyond that, have you got Firebug or a similar developer console in your browser? That helps a LOT.  It'll give you much more detailed error messages, which should help. For example, if I run changeText() on your example page, Firebug says "ReferenceError: changeText is not defined", meaning there is no changeText() function in your code, so you can't run it.

Answer (score 0):

First thing is that the changeText() function does not exist.

Secondly, you have this line at the end of your JavaScript tag which does NOT await execution after the entire page has been rendered. Since browsers execute any JavaScript code, inside the `head` tag before they finish rendering the rest of the html, then this line fails due to it wanting to access DOM objects that haven't yet been processed by the browser.

```
document.getElementById('mytextarea').innerHTML = "The text has been changed!";
```